# Write a text file from user input on a website to populate variables

Tags: php, file, shell

I am trying to create a simple website with user input dialog boxes to populate variables that will be used in a **shell command**.

I know probably the easiest thing to do is use HTML forms and then call the php file to write to the file.  I found some code for something similar but how can I use the input to populate variables?  Example is below.

I want the end result to be something like the following.

> testapp -d -p -e MySQL_dbname=$variable1 -e MySQL_dbuser=$variable2 -e MySQL_server=$variable3 -e MySQL_pass=$variable3

This is the code that I have found already

```
<form action="myprocessingscript.php" method="POST">
    <input name="field1" type="text" />
    <input name="field2" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) {
        $data = $_POST['field1'] . '-' . $_POST['field2'] . "\n";
        $ret = file_put_contents('/tmp/mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        if($ret === false) {
     die('There was an error writing this file');
}
else {
    echo "$ret bytes written to file";
}
}
else {
die('no post data to process');
}
```

Comment: what is the problem with it?

Comment: Please don't make me test this and call the kettle black.

Comment: It does write to a file but I am having trouble figuring out how to populate them into the variables in the shell command.

Comment: well well well... that's a whole different animal and ballgame there. You should have included that *bit* of information in your question *right off the bat* as well as adding/using the proper tag(s) for it.

Comment: My apologies, first time poster.  What would the proper tags be?

Comment: I made a few edits to your question. Let's see if anyone picks up on it. Tags are equally important when posting a question. Good luck, I sincerely wish you well, *cheers*

Comment: So you can't create a string or what?

Comment: Yes that is the part I am having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the output I was after by using concatenation, although each variable prints to a new line.  Any ideas how I can get it to output all on the same line?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2']) && isset($_POST['field3']) && isset($_POST['field4']) && isset($_POST['field5'])) {
    $containername = $_POST['field1'] . "\n";
    $WPhost = $_POST['field2'] . "\n";
    $WPuser = $_POST['field3'] . "\n";
    $WPpass = $_POST['field4'] . "\n";
    $WPname = $_POST['field5'] . "\n";
    $WPapp = 'testapp run -d --name';
    $WPdbhost = '-e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=';
    $WPdbuser = '-e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=';
    $WPdbpass = 'WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=';
    $WPdbname = '-e WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=';
    $ret = file_put_contents('/tmp/mydata.txt', $WPapp . ' ' . $WPhost . $WPdbhost . $WPuser . $WPdbuser . $WPpass . $WPdbname . $WPname, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
 die('There was an error writing this file');
}
else {
echo "$ret bytes written to file";
}
}
else {
die('no post data to process');
}
```

Comment: Just needed to remove "\n" from each.